# How to deserialize array of two lists in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an array of two lists. Each list contains objects. The objects in the first list are different from the objects in the second list. In JSON it looks like this:

```
[  
    {  
        "domains":  
        [  
            {  
                "attrb1": "aaaa",  
                "attrb2": "bbbb"  
            },
            {  
                "attrb1": "cccc",  
                "attrb2": "dddd"  
            }  
        ]  
    },  
    {     
        "terms":  
        [  
            {  
                "attrb1": "cccc",  
                "attrb2": "dddd"  
            }  
        ]  
    }  
]
```

I saved this JSON String to the file initial-elements-v02.json and I was thinking about something like this to deserialize it:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<List<Object>> glossaryElements = null;
   try {
       glossaryElements = mapper.readValue(
               arg0.resourceAsStream("initial-elements-v02.json"),
               new TypeReference<ListList<<Object>>>() {
               });
```

Thank you!
Evgeny

Answer (score 1):

According to [Data Binding with Generics](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Data_Binding_with_Generics), I would build from the innermost to the outside

```
Map<String, String>

List<Map<String, String>>

Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>

List<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>
```

and then use this

```
List<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> glossaryElements = null;
glossaryElements = mapper.readValue(
        arg0.resourceAsStream("initial-elements-v02.json"),
        new TypeReference<List<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>>() {});
```

If `initial-elements-v02.json` is the file name, I think you can also use

```
new File("initial-elements-v02.json")
```